# Androidでパーティカル？アニメーションを行いたい。

Tags: android

明確な質問ではなくて、申し訳ないのですが、 
Androidで、例えば画面上で花びらがヒラヒラと何枚も落ちてくるような、アニメーション？パーティクル？を作りたい場合、どのような方法で作る事が可能なのでしょうか？ 
また、皆様のおすすめの方法などありましたら、ご回答頂けますと幸いです。

イメージはこういうものです。 
[参考](http://kafe3232.exblog.jp/21077016/)

画面を開いた時から、ひらひらと花びらが舞っているようなものを作りたいです。

Answer (score 1):

既に回答がありますが、Animationを使う方法ではいかがでしょうか？
下記例では花びらが１つのみで単純な動きしかしていませんが、
Animationの速度や動きなどの変更、複数表示、Viewごとに動きを変える、
花びら画像をリアルなものに変更などの修正でもっとよく見えるようになると思います。

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hana_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hana"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

res/anim/fall_anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="6000"
        android:fromXDelta="50%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXDelta="50%p"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="-150%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXDelta="150%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"/>
</set>
```

res/drawable/hana.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffc0cb"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="40dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="40dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

src/MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fall_anim);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.hana_image);
        imageView.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！こちらを参考にさせていただき、アニメーションでも作ってみます。

Answer (score 0):

言語は Java ではなく C++ になりますが、cocos2d-x v3 を使うのはどうでしょうか？
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/

cocos2d-x であれば、パーティクルが標準でサポートされていています。
最新の v3.5 では、３次元のパーティクルも新たにサポートされましたよ。

cocos2d-x でのパーティクルの具体的な実装方法は、同梱されている cpp-test
を見ればわかると思います。

Comment: やはりcocos2dですかね。
一度それも考えたのですが、C++になってしまうので、一旦保留おります。やはり、本当はそっちの方がいいのかもしれませんね。